# Finding Fifth Saturdays Mathematically?

Tags: mysql, math

So, where I work, my employees work alternating Saturdays: some employees are assigned to work the 1st and 3rd Saturdays of each month, some are assigned to work the 2nd and 4th Saturdays of each month.

One small problem arises: there are four months in the year which have five Saturdays. Which is easy enough to work around: 1st/3rd Employees work the 1st and 3rd Fifth Saturdays in the year and so on.

Some years have five months with fifth Saturdays, but we're not talking about that right now.

Anyway, to generate schedules for my employees, I first use the following code to generate a list of dates:

```
    select 
        curdate() - interval (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)) day as Date
    from (
        select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as a
        cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as b
        cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as c
        ) as a
```

Then, I select the dates from the subquery, and join them to my Scheduling table to create a list of what each employee works on each date.

All of this works fine until Fifth Saturdays rear their ugly heads. At the moment, I use the following code to mathematically figure out which fifth saturday of the year it is:

```
mod(((datediff(date_add(a.date, interval (7-dayofweek(a.date)) day),date_add(subdate(a.Date,dayofyear(a.date-1)), interval (1-dayofweek(subdate(a.Date,dayofyear(a.date-1)))) day))+1)/7),4)
```

Or, to summarize, I find the number of days that have elapsed from the current first Sunday of the year to the current Saturday of this week, divide it by seven to figure out how many Saturdays have passed since then, and then find the modulo of 4 to figure out how many "extra" fifth Saturdays have passed since then.

...and this code will work perfectly fine *unless* the Fifth Saturday happens to fall on a week which is a multiple of four. Thankfully, that doesn't happen at all this year, but next year I'll need to figure out how to deal with this.

Is there a better way to mathematically figure out which fifth Saturday of the month a given fifth Saturday is?

Comment: Can you explain what you're actually trying to output from the SQL ? I don't understand what you're trying to achieve with it. This sort of calculation doesn't seem to *need* SQL but should be done with a programming language such as PHP and the *result* of this can then be manipulated by the MySQL database.

Comment: SQL is for the storage and retrieval of data. Attempting to do anything else with is, in my view, a mistake.

Comment: The output of this would be an integer, 1, 2, 3, or 4, inserted a WhichFifthSaturday? column which, in my join with the scheduling table, would be used to select the correct schedules. Also, while I *could* use another programming language to operate on this, I don't want to. I want to do it in SQL.

Comment: SQL isn't a programming language.

Comment: Steven, why do you try to do it the hard way? Wouldn't it be much easier to make schedule just "every second Saturday" with half of the employees starting this week and half - next week. IMHO this results in a better schedule with no 2 consecutive weeks to work on Saturday AND it is easier to compute this way.

Comment: I pitched that very idea SergGr 2. And was promptly shut down.

Comment: @StevenDay, here is another idea: there are only 14 types of years altogether (`7` for the week day of the January 1 times `2` for leap/non-leap). You may have your Saturdays schedules pre-generated (as shifts from January 1) for all 14 cases and then select the proper one by analyzing current year. The SQL might be not beautiful but should be not hard to auto-generate it. You might even put that data in a special table that you can join with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh man. I was way overthinking the SQL piece of this. It was actually pretty easy. Create three temporary tables: one to hold the completed date table, one to hold all of the dates of interest in your period, and a third table specifically to find Fifth Saturdays:

```
drop temporary table if exists DATES;
create temporary table DATES (AdherenceDates date, WhichSaturday int, 
WhichFifthSaturday int);
create temporary table DATES1 (AdherenceDates date, WhichSaturday int);
create temporary table DATES2 (FifthSaturdayDates date, WhichFifthSaturday 
int auto_increment, primary key (WhichFifthSaturday));
insert into DATES1 (AdherenceDates, WhichSaturday)
select
a.Date as AdherenceDates,
case
    when day(adddate(a.date,(7-dayofweek(a.date)))) <= 7
        then 1
    when day(adddate(a.date,(7-dayofweek(a.date)))) <= 14
        then 2      
    when day(adddate(a.date,(7-dayofweek(a.date)))) <= 21
        then 3
    when day(adddate(a.date,(7-dayofweek(a.date)))) <= 28
        then 4
    when day(adddate(a.date,(7-dayofweek(a.date)))) > 28
        then 5
end as WhichSaturday
from
(select 
    curdate() - interval (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a) + (1000 * d.a)) day 
as Date
from ( 
    select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 
union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 
union all select 8 union all select 9) as a
    cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union 
all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union 
all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as b
    cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union 
all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union 
all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as c
    cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union 
all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union 
all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as d
    ) as a
where dayofweek(a.Date) <> 1
and a.Date >= '2017-01-01'
order by a.Date asc
;
insert into DATES2 (FifthSaturdayDates)
select
a.Date as AdherenceDates
from
(select 
    curdate() - interval (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a) + (1000 * d.a)) day 
as Date
from ( 
    select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 
union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 
union all select 8 union all select 9) as a
    cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union 
all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union 
all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as b
    cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union 
all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union 
all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as c
    cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union 
all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union 
all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as d
    ) as a
where dayofweek(a.Date) = 7
and a.Date >= '2017-01-01'
and day(a.Date) > 28
order by a.date asc;
insert into DATES (AdherenceDates, WhichSaturday, WhichFifthSaturday)
select
DATES1.AdherenceDates,
DATES1.WhichSaturday,
DATES2.WhichFifthSaturday
from
DATES1
left join
DATES2
on DATES1.AdherenceDates = DATES2.FifthSaturdayDates;
drop temporary tables DATES1, DATES2;
select * from DATES
order by AdherenceDates asc;
```